# can I remove nemo

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, cinnamon

I have Cinnamon installed as my window manager on Ubuntu 14.04. I hate nemo. I need the functionality of nautilus-actions. Can I `sudo apt-get purge nemo*` to get nautilus to be my default file manager? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Nautilus is still  present on your system. Unless you removed it or removed unity

Comment: @Serg, nautilus is still present.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58063

Comment: Although you're the first one complaining about Nemo and wanting Nautilus... It should be possible if you had Unity installed before and did not remove it. But be careful and read the list `apt-get purge nemo*` prints to show _which packages will finally be removed_! If there is something you want to keep, better leave it installed. You should be able to use Nautilus and Nemo in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see that nemo is a fork of nautilus, and you can used the nemo-actions instead of nautilus-actions, there are some nautilus actions that are not ported to nemo yet, but could be easy.

I not recommend use nautilus and nemo at the same time, but well, i used both and you can decide if nemo will handle your desktop or will be nautilus.
You can not purge nemo or you will remove the cinnamon desktop. I think that this will be possible on the future, but not now, as Nemo is a dependency for the cinnamon desktop.